# Problem passing animatedPosition from BottomSheet to child to animate image

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, jsx, bottom-sheet

I cant seem to pass the onchange Y value from @gorhom/bottom-sheet. I can see the value when onchange in my App.js but I need to pass it another external component.

I am not sure if this involves using useDerivedValue or useEffect. I manage to pass the initial value from a state but even that is one behind.

I have an App.js that has the bottomSheet in it and another external .js file that loads images that are passed from the App.js, so everything is passing ok. Do I need to use useEffect to listen for changes?

As it stands I am using this in my App

```
const bottomSheetRef = useRef < BottomSheet > null;

  // variables
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => [200, 538], []);

  // callbacks
  const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index: number) => {
    console.log("handleSheetChanges", index);
  }, []);

  const animatedPosition = useSharedValue(0);

  const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = React.useState(0);

  useDerivedValue(() => {
    console.log(
      animatedPosition.value,
      "here you will get value of every position"
    );
  }, [animatedPosition]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentPosition);
  }, [currentPosition]);
```

And how I am using it,

```
<BottomSheet
          useRef={bottomSheetRef}
          index={1}
          snapPoints={snapPoints}
          // onChange={handleSheetChanges}
          animateOnMount={false}
          animatedPosition={animatedPosition}
          onChange={(index) => setCurrentPosition(index)}
        >
```

This all works great but when I try to pass it, it does not update, I am using this code in my exertnal file,

```
export default function BottomSheetData(props) {
  const {
    show,
    imga,
    imgb,
    imgc,
    selectedItem,
    imgWidthV,
    imgHeightV,
    animatedPosition,
  } = props;
```

which gets all the relevant data just not the "live" changes?

I have tried everything but its now causing me a headache!!! I hope I have explained this issue properly and provided enough code. All I need it being pointed in the right direction or being told I am going around this in the totally wrong way.